# calculate Up Vector of model

Tags: opengl

calculate Up Vector

here is my code:

```
Vector3f CameraUpVector() const
{
Vector3f cameraDirection = m_cameraTarget - m_cameraPosition;

cameraDirection = cameraDirection.Normalize();
////////////
Vector3f cameraUp = cameraDirection.Cross(Vector3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
return cameraUp;
}
//////////
Vector3f cameraUp = CameraUpVector();
///////////////
p.SetCamera(m_cameraPosition , m_cameraTarget , cameraUp);
```

Is this calculation OK?

if not-how can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will find the camera rolling around its forward vector. I would alter your code as follows (assuming right-handed coordinate system and world up vector is (0, 1, 0)):

```
Vector3f CameraUpVector() const
{
  Vector3f cameraDirection = m_cameraTarget - m_cameraPosition;
  Vector3f cameraRight = cameraDirection.Cross(Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
  Vector3f cameraUp = cameraRight.Cross(cameraDirection );

  return cameraUp.Normalize();
}
```

Note, that you should deal with the special case where the camera target is directly above or below the camera position (either by preventing that occurring or keeping a record of the last valid camera up vector and using it instead of the world up vector in this case)

Comment: now my target is (0,0,0)
and the camrea pos is (0,500,0) and the up vector is (0,1,)
and I cant see nothing.I will try this func.
my goal is waching the model from up. Is this possible with this func you corrected or should I change something else?Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: That's the "special case" I mentioned. I did make some assumptions in my answer. What is the general "up" vector in your world? If Y is up, and you're directly above the target, then there is no single "correct" answer. You could pick any vector in the plane Y=0.

Comment: my vector up is :

        Vector3f Up(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
after that I am setting the pos and target as I wrote and
p.SetCamera(m_cameraPosition , m_cameraTarget , cameraUp);
still I cant see nothing

Comment: The problem is the up vector is co-linear with the camera heading. You need to use a vector perpendicular to the heading - in your case (1,0,0), (0,0,1), or any other vector with y=0 and unit length would work.

Comment: do u mean to change the Vector3f Up(1.0, 0.0f, 0.0f)? and use the func you wrote?